# The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ and unitary correspondence with $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

The question I have is related to a problem in Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis, Chapter 4.

**The problem**
Let $\eta(t)$ be a fixed strictly positive continuous function $[a,b]$. Define $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ to be the space of all measurable functions $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^b |f(t)|^2\eta(t)dt<\infty.$$

Define the inner product on $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ by 
$$\langle f, g\rangle_\eta=\int_a^bf(t)\overline{g(t)}\eta(t)dt.$$

Show that $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ is a Hilbert space, and that the mapping $U:f\mapsto \eta^{1/2}f$ gives a unitary correspondence between $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ and the usual space $L^2[a,b]$.

**Discussion** It is not hard to show that $\langle f, g\rangle_\eta$ gives an inner product on $\mathcal{H}_\eta$, and once it is established that $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ is a Hilbert space, showing that $U$ is a Unitary mapping is not too difficult either- I have been able to complete these steps in full. The difficulty I am having is completing the proof that $\mathcal{H}_n$ is actually a Hilbert space.

To do this I must show that $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ is a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f, f\rangle }_\eta$, 
In particular, it remains to show $(\mathcal{H}_\eta, \|\cdot \|)$ is complete and separable.

I have an idea and perhaps you guys could provide some feedback on it. 
Let $f\in \mathcal{H}_\eta$. 
Since $[a,b]$ is compact, and $\eta(t)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $\eta(t)$ achieves its minimum on $[a,b]$ and since $\eta$ is strictly positive, 
$$ c:=\min_{\xi\in [a,b]}\eta(\xi)>0.$$
The monotonicity of the integral then gives:

$$\infty>\|f\|_{\mathcal{H}_\eta}=\int_a^b |f(t)|^2\eta(t)dt\geq  \min_{\xi\in [a,b]}\eta(\xi) \int_a^b |f(t)|^2dt =c\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]} \enspace (*)$$
This gives $f\in L^2[a,b]$. 
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}_\eta$, i.e. 
$$\lim_{n,m\to\infty} \|f_n-f_m\|_{\mathcal{H}}=0$$

By $(*)$ we also have $\|f_n-f_m\|_{L^2[a,b]}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty,m\to \infty$. Thus $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2[a,b]$ and since $L^2$ is complete there exists $f\in L^2[a,b]$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-f\|_{L^2[a,b]}=0$.

Observe now that $\eta(t)$ (being continuous on a compact interval) achieves its maximum $d:=\max_{\xi\in [a,b]}\eta(\xi)>0$
and 
$$\int_a^b |f(t)|^2\eta(t)dt\leq d\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}<\infty\enspace (**)$$
so $f$ is also in $\mathcal{H}_n$ and we have by $(**)$ that 
$$\frac{1}{d}\|f_n-f\|_{\mathcal{H}_\eta}<\|f_n-f\|_{L^2[a,b]}\to 0$$ 
so $\lim_{n\to infty}\|f_n-f\|_{\mathcal{H}_\eta}=0$ and thus 
$\mathcal{H}_\eta$ is complete.

Is this correct? 
As for separability, I am not as confident. I am guessing I can use a similar density argument since $L^2[a,b]$ is separable.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I am pretty sure the relations $(*)$ and $(**)$ will give that $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ is separable, since there is a countable dense subset in $L^2[a,b]$, such a subset is also dense in $\mathcal{H}_\eta$, by these relations